# How to display variable values by hovering over the variable

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hover

I am used to get directly the current value of an element by hovering it. However, it seems to work differently in Eclipse. Is there a way to change the hovering output?

Example:
Assume that I have an ArrayList "list" of an object "myObject" with the attributes "name" and "value".
I'd like to debug element "i" of the "list" in the following line of code:

```
list.get(i).name;
```

The element i contains the value name=Test and value=1. What I'd like to see is "Test" or "name=Test" hovering over "name". However, I get "String packagePath.myObject".

For this short list of element calls, I could write a "toString" function in "myObject" to see the right output. However, this is not really working if I have more calls in a row. Thus, is there a simple option to show up my variable values directly?

edit: minimal example

```
package testHovering;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class mainHover {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    class myObject{
        public String name;
        public int value;
        public myObject(String name, int value) {
            this.name=name;
            this.value=value;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<myObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new myObject("Test", 1));

    String temp = list.get(0).name; 
    System.out.println(temp);

    System.out.println(list.get(0).name);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For not recurrent inspections**

What you are looking for is the `inspect` option.
During the debugging, as the debugger is paused on a statement, follow these steps :

- select the expression to evaluate
- then right-click and select "inspect" OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

It will execute the selected expression.

Here is a preview :

[image]

Note that it may have side effect on the application behavior if the expression has a side effect on the object itself or another object.
For example if you inspect an expression such as :

```
list.add("a string");
```

This will be executed twice : a first time for the inspection and then a second time for the normal execution.

**For recurrent inspections**

If you need to watch an expression multiple times, using the "watch" feature is more suitable.
You can make an expression to be watched during debugging in the same way as for inspecting them but this time by selecting the "watch" option.

Here is a preview with this way :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it is not working. I get the error message "name cannot be resolved to a variable". Maybe I have to build up a complete minimum example to show you a specific use case.
The recurrent inspection is not necessary. I am more interested in a one-time value inspection.

Comment: You have to inspect at a time where the expression is resolvable by the debugger, that is in your case as the object is initialized and be accessible in the current execution scope.

Comment: I added a minimal example. Probably I am doing something wrong. I marked "list.get(0).name" in the line "String temp = list.get(0).name;" and got the error "Evaluations must contain either an expression or a block of well-formed statements" now.